# GetQueuedCompletionStatus causes CPU spikes at timable scenarios?

Tags: c#, chromium, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

[image]

The first spike is somewhat my own code, but the 2nd one highlighted is not and is seemingly from "KERNELBASE" (`KERNELBASE!GetQueuedCompletionStatus`) or libcef.dll (Chromium used with CEFSharp).

As you can see, it spiked to 100% and STAYS 100%. It will stay like that for a good 5-10 seconds. You can tell its a HARD 100% with the fact visual-studio couldn't continue it's timing procedures and because of that, it looks like its a 1 ms spike.

So on my end, to get this to occur, all I have to do is start a certain function on my application (its async/await loop) and if I were to pause it, (using a semaphoreslim) before the spike happens, It will STILL spike. Essentially meaning its NOT my code. The Spike happens pretty much at the same time every time once I start that async/await loop. Its roughly 11-12 seconds after it starts that it happens.

At first I assumed it was caused by using CEFSharp's C# -> JS communication stuff but it doesnt seem likely as for the test I have removed all my code using it entirely.

After research some people had a similar issue because of Intel's Power-Saving features usually found in Intel Pentiums from 2010 ish. But im using an intel i7-7700k so this is super unlikely.

Strangely this only happens when I use my proxy-variant of the code. If I do the code without a proxy, the spike doesn't occur. Meaning it's somewhat narrowed down but I still cannot figure out for the life of me why it's occurring.

Any debugging ideas would be greatly appreciated.
Due to the nature of this, I literally can't provide any code as it could be occurring anywhere in my 300+ lines of code.

After @HansPassant told me to try disabling my Anti-Virus, Strangely, that worked (Somewhat).
[image]

It may look like theres generally MORE cpu usage, but thats because I re-enabled all the C#->JS Communication code. But the 2 spikes the Starting one and the main-topic one both stayed "spiked" for WAY less. First one, like idk half a second, the second one for about 1-2 seconds tops.

So it did very well help, but as you can see, CEFSharp is still doing quite a lot of stuff for some reason causing CPU usage.

Comment: Hmm, getting every single thread to burn 100% core at the exact same time is pretty special, nobody knows how to write code like that.  Tends to be the kind of rootkit that programmers voluntarily install on their machine.  Disable the installed anti-malware product and try again.

Comment: @HansPassant Was using latest malwarebytes officially and licenced. Seems like that was causing it partially. The moment I turned it off, CPU went a LOT smoother. But it still occassionally spiked, Now usually around 23-24 seconds and doesnt last as long, now maybe 1-2 seconds.

Comment: What version are you using? What does your code look like? What proxy are you referring to? JavaScript proxy? Last time I checked they had horrible performance. How does Chrome of the exact same version behave?